# Express sendfile and redirect url

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express

I have a bunch of middleware. At the first `app.use` I test if the process is under duress, and if so I want it to just send the static `/index.html` file and redirect the user's browser to `"/#" + req.url`.

for example:

```
app.set("port", PORT)
//etc
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (something)
    res.sendfile('/public/index.html', { root: __dirname + '/..' })
    // also, redirect the user to '/#' + req.url
  else
    next()
});
// a ton more middleware that deals with the main site
app.use(express.static(...))
```

Right now, it just sends the index.html to whatever url they're at. How can I redirect them to "/" and serve index.html without messing up any future middleware.

Comment: You can obviously call [`res.redirect('/')`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) but I have a feeling that's not exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: The static files are not mounted until after the app middleware, so redirecting to '/' doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but try this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (something && req.path !== '/')
    return res.redirect('/');
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (something)
    return res.sendfile('/public/index.html', { root: __dirname + '/..' });
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(...));
```

Comment: Is res.redirect() somehow similar to res.sendfile() but it starts/redirects to a new url whereas res.sendfile() keeps the url? res.redirect() has/uses a 301 http status code? I do not know when use which method.

Comment: @Timo `sendfile()` sends the contents of a file as a response, `redirect()` tells the browser to retrieve a different URL than the one it just retrieved. Those are two different things. A link to a route that performs `sendfile()` will _typically_ not cause a browser to change the URL.