# Can't set headers after they are sent, Redirecting from SendFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Scenario is:

I want to load a webpage (it loads with sendFile) then I want to create a setTimeout timer and redirect the user to another webpage with sendFile also, but I'm getting the headers error.

- I've tried a CORS approach like said in other answers (including all headers before each request with app.use)
- I've tried to res.end() but it won't just load the first website.

## App use

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
   res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PUT');
   res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');
   next();
})
```

## Redirect of first webpage show.

```
res.redirect(`/pantallas/reloj?tiempo=${Response.rows[0].Tiempo_refresco}&next=${Response.rows[1].Ruta_pantalla}`)
res.end()
```

## Route to show first webpage and then redirecting to second one.

```
// Being tiempo = 5 and next = '/pantallas/barras'


app.get('/pantallas/reloj', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/pantallas/reloj.html'));
  if(req.query.tiempo)
   {
     setTimeout(() => {
         res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + req.query.next));
     }, req.query.tiempo * 1000);
   }
  })
```

At this point it loads the first website then after the timer is done it just throws the headers error, any help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are sending the response twice. Hence, the error:
Can't set headers after they are sent.

You cannot return a response twice from the same route, you are sending a file first via the response and then once again inside the set timeout. This is not permitted.

**Why is this happening?**

> The res object in Express is a subclass of Node.js's
>   http.ServerResponse (read the http.js source). You are allowed to call
>   res.setHeader(name, value) as often as you want until you call
>   res.writeHead(statusCode). After writeHead, the headers are baked in
>   and you can only call res.write(data), and finally res.end(data).

The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode. When you see this error, try to look for anything that tries to send a header after some of the body has already been written. For example, look for callbacks that are accidentally called twice, or any error that happens after the body is sent.

**EDIT:**

You can try something along these lines:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.tiempo) {
      setTimeout(() => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + req.query.next));
      }, req.query.tiempo * 1000);
  }
  next();
});

app.get('/pantallas/reloj', function(req, res, next) {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/pantallas/reloj.html'));
     next();
});
```

More here: [Express sendfile and redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900557/express-sendfile-and-redirect-url)

Comment: Then how I could achieve the desired effect of a redirect after a route is loaded since it's not permitted by Express?