# Getting 404 on page refresh - LitElement

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I have used **`lit-element-router`** and when i try refreshing the app, page with static routes are refreshing but getting a **`404`** for dynamic routes.

```
static get routes() {
    return [{
        name: 'home',
        pattern: '',
        data: {
            title: 'Home'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'info',
        pattern: 'info'
    }, {
        name: 'employee',
        pattern: 'employee/:id'
    }, {
        name: 'not-found',
        pattern: '*'
    }];
}
```

When i try refreshing the employee page. I am getting **`404`**.

**Question:** How can i stay in that dynamic route without getting a **`404`** on refresh?

Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by static/dynamic route?

Comment: @Umbo Dynamic route is when i try passing any id as a route param and would change as per the user request

Comment: Is your server rewriting urls to `index.html`?

Comment: @Umbo I have no server file in particular. Serving the app with node server

Comment: You need to redirect all requests to `/`. If you have an express.js server maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900557/express-sendfile-and-redirect-url